# Using variable in relative range instead of absolute value

Tags: excel, vba

This code is working fine:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sum(R[-6]C:R[-1]C)"
```

But instead of -6 in row I want to put a defined variable - lets say I define `x` and then I write it as follows:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sum(R[-x]C:R[-1]C)"
```

But that gives me an error. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the constant `Text` part of your formula with the Variable, you do that by adding `"` before and after followed by the `&`. Like: `" & x & "`

Try the code below:

```
Dim x As Long

x = 6
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sum(R[-" & x & "]C:R[-1]C)"
```

**Note**: Try avoid using `ActiveCell`, instead use fully qualified `Cells` and `Range`. For instance:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D10").FormulaR1C1 = "=Sum(R[-" & x & "]C:R[-1]C)"
```